# How to calculate different well-known similarity or distance measures between two vectors in R?

Tags: r, distance, similarity, measure

I want to compute the similarity (distance) between two vectors:

```
v1 <- c(1, 0.5, 0, 0.1)
v2 <- c(0.7, 1, 0.2, 0.1)
```

I just want to know if a package is available for calculating different well-known similarity (distance) measures in R? For example, "Resnik", "Lin", "Rel", "Jiang",...

The implementation of these method is not hard, but I really think it must be defined in some packages in R.

After some googling I found a package ["GOSemSim"](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GOSemSim/inst/doc/GOSemSim.pdf), which contains most measures, but it's specific to the biomedical application and I can't use them for computing the similarity between two vectors.

Comment: The code is open-sourced.

Comment: What is the list of similarity measures you need access to?

Answer (score 11):

"[proxy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/index.html)" is a general library for distance and similarity measures. The following methods are supported:

"Jaccard"         "Kulczynski1"     "Kulczynski2"     "Mountford"       "Fager"           "Russel"          "simple matching" "Hamman"          "Faith"
"Tanimoto"        "Dice"            "Phi"             "Stiles"          "Michael"         "Mozley"          "Yule"            "Yule2"           "Ochiai"
"Simpson"         "Braun-Blanquet"  "cosine"          "eJaccard"        "fJaccard"        "correlation"     "Chi-squared"     "Phi-squared"     "Tschuprow"
"Cramer"          "Pearson"         "Gower"           "Euclidean"       "Mahalanobis"     "Bhjattacharyya"  "Manhattan"       "supremum"        "Minkowski"
"Canberra"        "Wave"            "divergence"      "Kullback"        "Bray"            "Soergel"         "Levenshtein"     "Podani"          "Chord"
"Geodesic"        "Whittaker"       "Hellinger"

Check the following example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(4,5,6,7,8)
l <- list(x, y)
simil(l, method="cosine")
```

The output is a similarity matrix between the elements of "l":

```
      1
2     0.978232
```

The only problem I have is that for some methods (such as: "Jaccard"), the following error is occurred:

```
simil(l, method="Jaccard")
Error in n - d : 'n' is missing
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dist` function supports via its `method` argument: "euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski".   See `?dist`